# How could I solve this issue related to Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have this error when I launched npx nodemon index.js related to Mongoose.connect. I have also a .env file with the config var value. I will appreciate your comments.

Here is my code:

```
// Import des packages
const express = require("express");
const formidableMiddleware = require("express-formidable");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv").config();

// Activation des packages
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(formidableMiddleware());

// Connexion à la Base de données
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});

// Imports des routes
const formRoutes = require("./routes/form");
app.use(formRoutes);

// Routes

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "Welcome" });
});

app.all("*", function (req, res) {
  res.json({ message: "Page not found" });
});

// Démarrage du serveur
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server started");
});
```

[image: the error in my console]

Comment: "_I have this error_" not getting what is the error here? Could you please elaborate.

Comment: The error is the following:   MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/yoniabittan/LeReacteur/Certification/back-formnest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:582:11)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/yoniabittan/LeReacteur/Certification/back-formnest/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:335:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yoniabittan/LeReacteur/Certification/back-formnest/index.js:14:10)

Comment: @Yoni Looks like `process.env.MONGODB_URI` is `undefined`. Do a `console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI)` before  calling the `mongoose.connect`

Comment: @Vishnu thanks for your message.I console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI) and I got the same error message: ('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a ' +). Really strange since my MongoDB works and the Heroku deployment of my back works well too. Any idea to fix this issue ?

Comment: @Yoni. Please check whether `undefined` is printed in the console just above the error message. console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI) will print `undefined` if its not able to find `MONGODB_URI`

Comment: yes I got an "undefined" when I console.log(process.env.MONGODB_URI). What is the solution to fix the issue please? When I launch my Mongo DB, it works and the deployment of my back to Heroku worked fine too. Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: thank you I fix the bug by changing the position of my .env file